# Why did my ice maker inlet freeze over?

Tags: ice-maker

Woke up to find icicles hanging from the ice maker today! Looks like the inlet froze over but the ice maker kept on dispensing water to make more ice?!

How does this happen and how can I stop it from happening again?

Also, what’s the easiest why to clean this out without defrosting the entire freezer?

[image]

Comment: a sponge ... it will be liquid when defrosted

Comment: Maybe an ice pick?

Comment: Brand & model of the fridge in question will help us help you. Does the instruction manual have anything to say about it? There's usually a "troubleshooting tips" section toward the rear...